# Aurora serverless cooldown time to scale down

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

The documentation at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.how-it-works.html states the following:

> After scaling up, the cooldown period for scaling down is 15 minutes.
>   After scaling down, the cooldown period for scaling down again is 310
>   seconds.

It turns out my users have weird application usage cycles and they all use the app every 25 minutes or so and then they all stop using it. I would like to manually change the cooldown period to fit this requirement but haven't find out a way of doing it. 
Any ideas?

Comment: If the scaling cooldowns are set by AWS, then I doubt you can change them.

Answer (score 2):

If there are literally zero connections at certain times, you can [modify](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.modifying.html) the Aurora cluster to auto-pause after a minimum of 5 minutes of inactivity:

`aws rds modify-db-cluster \
--db-cluster-identifier sample-cluster \
--scaling-configuration MinCapacity=1,MaxCapacity=32,TimeoutAction='ForceApplyCapacityChange',SecondsUntilAutoPause=300,AutoPause=true`

If there are still some users and you can programmatically see that the usage has dropped, you can [force a capacity change](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.how-it-works.html#aurora-serverless.how-it-works.timeout-action) sooner than the normal cooldown by calling:

`aws rds modify-current-db-cluster-capacity --db-cluster-identifier sample-cluster --capacity 1`

You can't force capacity to 0, but if you have autoPause set to "true" you can force to the minimum allowable value (1 ACU) and then wait for the 5 minutes of no activity for auto-pause to kick in.

> You can change the capacity of an Aurora Serverless DB cluster. When you change the capacity, Aurora Serverless tries to find a scaling point for the change. If Aurora Serverless can't find a scaling point, it times out. You can specify one of the following actions to take when a capacity change times out:
>
> Force the capacity change – Set the capacity to the specified value as soon as possible.
>
> Roll back the capacity change – Cancel the capacity change.
>
> Important: If you force the capacity change, connections that prevent Aurora Serverless from finding a scaling point might be dropped.